# How to solve $\int{\frac{6}{(x^2+(\sqrt{x^2})-4)}}\mathrm dx?$ Please help me out.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve
$$\int{\frac{6}{(x^2+(\sqrt{x^2})-4)}}\mathrm dx?$$

I am trying this question by taking first of all $x^2$ out of the root sign. Now I am getting the integral to be $\int{\frac{6}{(x^2+|x|-4)}}\mathrm dx$. But how to approach further? Because now there will be 2 integrals due to $|x|$. One will be $\int{\frac{6}{(x^2+x-4)}}\mathrm dx$ and second $\int{\frac{6}{(x^2-x-4)}}\mathrm dx$. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you evaluate the individual antiderivatives e.g. via partial fraction decomposition? Then you should just "glue" them at 0.

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to say@Amateur_Algebraist. First of all x²+x-4 and x²-x-4 can't be factorized into two terms.

Comment: **Hint**: Start with transformation $|x|=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\cdot x$. Continue with grouping, i.e. completing the square, and then proceed with substitution $u=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{2}+x$.

Comment: Thank you very much @AntonVrdoljak.

Comment: You're welcome @DEBSANKARROY!

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY $x^2+x-4 = (x + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}) (x + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2})$, and similarly for $x^2-x-4$.

Answer (score 1):

A. When $x>0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{6}{x^2+x-4} d x \\
& =12 \int \frac{1}{(2 x+1)^2-17} d(2 x+1) \\
& =\frac{6}{\sqrt{17}} \ln \left| \frac{2 x+1-\sqrt{17}}{2x+1+\sqrt{17}}\right| +C
\end{aligned}
$$
B. When $x<0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{6}{x^2-x-4} d x \\
& =12 \int \frac{1}{(2 x-1)^2-17} d(2 x-1) \\
& =\frac{6}{\sqrt{17}} \ln \left| \frac{2 x-1-\sqrt{17}}{2x-1+\sqrt{17}}\right| +C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Why : $I  =\int \frac{6}{x^2+x-4} d x \\
 =12 \int \frac{1}{(2 x+1)^2-17} d(2 x+1)$

Comment: $\begin{aligned} 4\left(x^2+x-4\right) & =4 x^2+4 x-16 \\ & =(2 x+1)^2-17\end{aligned}$