# How to evaluate the above integration. Kindly help me out.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \frac{77\ dx}{(x^2+(x^2)^{1/2}-66)} \tag 1$$ I am trying this question by taking $x^2$ out of the square root sign. Now $x^2$ will become $|x|$. So, the final expression will become $$\int \frac{77\ dx}{x^2+|x|-66}\tag 2$$  Now I am facing problem to integrate this expression further. I can't proceed further. The only thing I have thought is that $|x|$ can be written as $x\cdot(\text{sgn}(x))$. Please help me out.

Comment: Just use https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: How to solve it without using calculator? I have seen the solution in Wolfram Alpha also but not understood the solution

Comment: Look at the answer to this very similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782468/how-to-solve-int-frac6x2-sqrtx2-4-mathrm-dx-please-help-me-ou?rq=1

Comment: I think this can help. For $x>0$: $x^2+x-66 = x^2+x+1/4-1/4-66 = (x+1/2)^2-1/4-66$. Now try the substitution method to solve the problem. Take the analogous approach for $x<0$.

Comment: @NikolaRistic, can there two solutions exist for an indefinite integral?

Comment: @ArijitGhosh When you solve an indefinite integral, you do not get a unique solution, just a family of solutions that differ by the value of the integration constant. Any solution of that family of solutions is still a solution. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Ok. Thank you@NikolaRistic.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- $x \le 0 => x^2+|x|-66 = x^2-x-66$
- $x \ge 0 => x^2+|x|-66 = x^2+x-66$

In both cases, you have a second-degree polynomial with a discriminant larger than zero ($265$ to be exact), so you can write them as $(x - a) \cdot (x - b)$.

Then you just use "partial fractions" for solving the integral.